# How can I make it so that when I click on a layout, its data is copied and sent to Firebase?

Tags: java, android

I have an activity with a RecyclerView that contains information. I fill out a form, submit it, then the data is entered into Firebase and the Activity displays the item with the data that I entered.
I want to make it so that when I click on any such item, it is copied to a separate table and then I can display it in another Activity. That is, I want to make an Add to Favorites button.

I've tried doing it myself, but I'm stumped.

In the adapter I tried to call the event handler and pass the data from the element I clicked on. But I'm sure this is wrong. And I don't know how to add to Firebase now.

```
 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CardAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    CardData userData = this.cardData.get(position);
    holder.favButn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Favourites.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", userData.getId());
                intent.putExtra("lastname", userData.getUserLastName());
                intent.putExtra("fullName", userData.getUserName());
                intent.putExtra("phone", userData.getUserPhone());
                intent.putExtra("email", userData.getUserEmail());

                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

If I do that, and if it works, as far as I understand it, there will only be 1 item on the page where I will be redirected after clicking.
But I want to be able to add at least as many items to favorites on one screen (and they wouldn't disappear from here), then go to the Favourites screen and see them there.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The first option to solve this is to save Favourites on the `Firebase database` in relation to your user. Each time you open the Favorites class just retrieve this information and apply them to your layout. This will always trigger wifi or network on your phone which will have some impact on battery life and/or optimization of your application.

My suggestion is to on the "`addToFavorites`" button you save your data to the local database or `SharedPreferences`. This way you can get this data even if the user doesn't have an internet connection.

**Database**

For a database, you can use `SQLite` or `Room` `DB` for `Android`. It's easy to use and you can implement it fast. Also, you can do a lot with this later if you need it in your app.

**SharedPreferences**

Using `SharedPreferences` you can save your favorites as `String` under some `KEY` like "Favourites". Each time you add a new one you can retrieve information from SharedPreferences based on your `KEY`, add a new value, and save it. In your Favourites class, you can just retrieve your `KEY` and use data to fill your layout. Here you can use something like `JSONArray` to save all your Favourites and then convert it to string to save it to SharedPreferences and from `String` convert it back to `JSONArray`. This is an easy process since `JSONArray` has `.toString()` and `new JSONArray(string)` methods and constructors.

**Things to keep in mind**
***Firebase*** 
**Advantage**: Clearing cache won't affect as data is stored online 
 **Disadvantage**: No internet no favourite list

***SharedPreferences***
**Advantage**: Clearing cache will flush out whole data  
**Disadvantage**: Available all time, very fast

Comment: I can't give up Firebase. This is the architecture of my application.

Comment: @Fathpath I didn't tell you to give up firebase. You can still use it. Like I said you can save your Favorites in the Firebase database or just save it to local storage. What you do with the rest of the app and firebase is not related to this solution.

Comment: Ok, I get it. But I asked the question because I don't know how to save the data in the database.

Comment: @Fathpath oh, sorry. Then you can read this documentation. You can create a field inside every user to bind Favourites to him. Check this link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write ... So you would use something like this: mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).child("favourites").setValue(fav_list);

Comment: And since you can save List<Object> there just create a Favourites model in your project and save List<Fravourite> with each of your users.